# Why LaTex equation doesn't recognize characters such as "(" , "+" or hat?

Tags: equations, symbols, characters

I have this equation coded in LaTex :

> \^{y}$_i^k$ = $R_k^i$($x_i$)

I would like to print it to LaTex equation format thanks to the commande :

```
\begin{equation} \label{...}
...
\end{equation}
```

so I ran

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq2}
    \hat{y}_i^k = R_k^i(x_i)
\end{equation}
```

but as result I get :

```
yki  Rikxi    (1)
```

the variable y has not hat and "=" and "()" disappear. How is it possible to correct that ?

I precise that I use the following packages :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french]{rnti}

    \usepackage{ifxetex}

    \ifxetex
      \usepackage{fontspec}
    \else
      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
      \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \usepackage{lmodern}
      \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
    \fi
\usepackage{float}

 \usepackage{url}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\Fr


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! And how do you compile?  Anyway, please post a small compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` , till `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Overleaf. I have edited my post to add more details.

Comment: Please read a standard introduction to latex and especially math mode. You seem to be mixing everything up: $ \hat{y}$_i^k =$R_k^i(x_i)$, and don't ignore errors in your editor or on overleaf

Comment: And there is `\Fr` defined?

Comment: Your document clas is not know to Overleaf. replacing it with   `article` gives expected correct result (if I `\Fr` in your document example replace with showed equation).

Comment: Problem resolved by simply add "\usepackage{mathspec}" before "\usepackage{fontspec}".

Answer (score 1):

Solved in comments: *"Problem resolved by simply add `\usepackage{mathspec}` before `\usepackage{fontspec}`."*